# How to store image path in sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming. Can any body tell me that how to store image path in sqlite database,i now how to store image in database but i dont want to store image.I want to store only path of the image in photo gallery.

Please can any body tell me. Thanks

Comment: Have you even tried anything yet? Simply asking us to code something for you won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **UIImagePicker** delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {    

    NSURL *imageURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

     //save the URL to database
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replay.Acctually i got path of the image .now i want ot store that path in database.if i select image from gallery it has to store that image path in database.Can u please tell how to do this

Comment: just convert the imageURL to Nsstring and save it to  database. like  NSString *myString = [imageURL absoluteString]; // save myString to db

Comment: the url will be like assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000003&ext=JPG

Comment: if you want to display the image back using the saved url, just use ALAsset Library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone

Comment: hi iam directly storing path in database.now how can i get all store image path

Comment: Hi i have store some image path in database and i retrieve that image from database after that i store all image path in array from database.now i want to display all images in thumbnail.How can i do that.Please can any body help me

Comment: see my answer her http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322289/how-to-show-the-specific-image-from-photolibrary/11322770#11322770

Comment: and one more thing i have more than 20 images path are there in array. i want to display all images how can i display all images.

Comment: Thank u so much its working  
and one more thing i have more than 20 images path are there in array. i want to display all images how can i display all images.

Comment: use a for loop and  iterate the urls and display the images

Answer (score 0):

if you use [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) as SQLite wrapper, then it's a simply insert like: `[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable (name) VALUES (?)", YOUR_IMAGE_PATH]`. Otherwise if plain SQLite, you may refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871816/sqlite-insert-data-in-objective-c)

Comment: Hi i have store some image path in database and i retrieve that image from database after that i store all image path in array from database.now i want to display all images in thumbnail.How can i do that.Please can any body help me

Comment: what's your question then? How to get all the image paths from database or how to display an image with its path?

Comment: i have stored some images path in database.now i want to display that stored images.how can i do that

Comment: you need to be more specific about the question

Comment: Acctually i stored some images path in sqlitedatabase and also i retrieve that images paths also in console which i have stored in database.Now i have images path now i want to display all this images in next view.

Comment: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=D714F0AA-AF90-4D1C-947B-0A55EEEC0CEA&ext=JPG",

    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=60B4821E-2AAA-4C33-97E1-3320DB9C4E77&ext=JPG",

    "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=CF461579-BB37-45F0-9A2E-1EF3BAAEB063&ext=JPG",

Comment: iam getting path like this. i tried but its not display image

Comment: If asset path, then you may refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777282/how-to-get-image-path-from-photo-library-and-how-to-retrieve-the-image-from-phot)

Comment: and i store these path in array.inside the array some many paths r there. now i want to display all this path images. how can i do .

Comment: Either edit your question or move this discussion to chat. I can't just answer all the questions in comment...